# How to build Shallot

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am trying to build [Shallot](https://github.com/katmagic/Shallot/). I run x64 Debian Sqeeze. It runs into compile problems I don't understand...

```
john@hayek:~/build/katmagic-Shallot-831de01$ make
cc  -O3 -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib  -Wall -o src/math.o -c src/math.c
In file included from src/math.c:3:
src/math.h:23:24: error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory
src/math.h:24:25: error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
src/math.h:25:25: error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/math.c:3:
src/math.h:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/math.h:29: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/math.h:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/math.c:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
src/math.c:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
src/math.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make: *** [src/math.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
src/math.h:23:24: error: openssl/bn.h: No such file or directory
src/math.h:24:25: error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
src/math.h:25:25: error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing you don't have OpenSSL installed, or at least not the development package that includes headers. If you do, the headers aren't in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`, since that's where Shallot looks by default. You can add your own include path by running:

```
$ make CFLAGS=-I/path/to/openssl
```

On Debian, these files can be found in the `libssl-dev` package which you can install with `apt-get` or your favorite package management too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on CentOS 6on and fixed it by installing `openssl-devel`. Run this command as root:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```